# Onclick event with "if"

Tags: php, html

I have a php file with a submit button. By clicking the button I should be directed to another page based on the value of the "$categoria" variable. I inserted some "if" inside the "onclick" event but clicking on the button nothing happens. How can I do? This is the code: (the $categoria variable contains the correct value)

```
 <input type="submit" name="mySubmit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" value="+" onclick="
  
  if (<?php $categoria ?>=='libri') {
    location.href='aggiungiLibro.php?categoria=<?php print $_GET['categoria']; ?>&stanza=<?php print $_GET['stanza']; ?>'
  }
  else if(<?php $categoria ?>=='cosmetici') {
    
    location.href='aggiungiCosmetico.php?categoria=<?php print $_GET['categoria']; ?>&stanza=<?php print $_GET['stanza']; ?>'
  }
  else if(<?php $categoria ?>=='medicinali') {
    location.href='aggiungiMedicinale.php?categoria=<?php print $_GET['categoria']; ?>&stanza=<?php print $_GET['stanza']; ?>'
  }
  else {
    location.href='aggiungiOggetto.php?categoria=<?php print $_GET['categoria']; ?>&stanza=<?php print $_GET['stanza']; ?>'
  }
  ">
```

Comment: `<?php $categoria ?>` will do nothing, you'd need to output it. Is `$categoria` even set?

Comment: Yes, $categoria contains the value I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a button or any JavaScript for this at all - generating a simple hyperlink will do the job.

The only bit of the URL which actually varies is the page name. So first set the appropriate page to target, based on `$categoria`, and then build the rest of the URL and put it into the HTML:

```
<?php
switch($categoria) {
    case 'libri':
       $page = 'aggiungiLibro.php';
       break;
    case 'cosmetici':
       $page = 'aggiungiCosmetico.php';
       break;
    case 'medicinali':
       $page = 'aggiungiMedicinale.php';
       break;
    default: 
       $page = 'aggiungiOggetto.php';
       break;
}

$url = $page."?categoria=".$_GET['categoria']."&stanza=".$_GET['stanza'];

?>

<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">+</a>
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much for helping, I'm so happy!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're making this too complicated by passing the IF statement to javascript. Instead, assign the page to a variable before this block, then echo only 1 URL:

```
<?php 
switch($categoria) {
    case 'libri':
       $page = 'aggiungiLibro.php';
       break;
    case 'cosmetici':
       $page = 'aggiungiCosmetico.php';
       break;
    case 'medicinali':
       $page = 'aggiungiMedicinale.php';
       break;
    default: 
       $page = 'aggiungiOggetto.php';
       break;
}
?>

<input type="submit" name="mySubmit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" value="+" onclick="<?php echo $page; ?>?categoria=<?php print $_GET['categoria']; ?>&stanza=<?php print $_GET['stanza']; ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I tried this but clicking on the button doesn't open any page for me. What could be the problem?

Comment: Look at the source in your browser. Does the URL look correct? Are there any errors in the Developer Console?